# How to create Preview window to display a string?

Tags: echo, scratch-buffer, previewwindow

I'm using a LSP plugin to call a command from the server, and currently it is logging the data using `echom`.

[image: Response]

My current code is like this:

```
function! PtypeCallback(result)
    echom json_encode(a:result)
endfunction
```

It was working, but for functions with larger types, The JSON string is truncated. Also I want to keep it for some time, preferably launching it in a preview window.

How can I open the preview-window using a custom created buffer which contains the `typ` parameter from the JSON I'm receiving in `a:result` parameter?

Comment: Take a look at scratch.vim plugin https://github.com/mtth/scratch.vim
Or check :he special-buffers

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation, check `:h pedit` to open the preview window with some custom file name.

Comment: @AlexKroll I want the preview window to be non-editable. This command is only useful to see what is the type of a function, and I get the contents from a parameter in a callback function. I've seen the help file for special-buffers, which is listing quickfix but not preview. This is supposed to contain documentation also if it is available, so I don't think a location list is useful.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Unfortunately I don't have a file. The response comes by means of a JSON RPC from the LSP plugin for me. I don't want to write it to a file only to load it into a buffer.

Comment: well, I don't see a way than to create a tempfile and display it in the preview window. (Note something like this might even work: `:exe 'pedit +call\ setline(1,text)' tempname()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seven hours of fiddling with the documentation and searching, I was able to write a function that takes a filetype, an array of strings and show a dummy buffer based on that.

```
function! showInPreview(name, fileType, lines)
    let l:command = "silent! pedit! +setlocal\\ " .
                  \ "buftype=nofile\\ nobuflisted\\ " .
                  \ "noswapfile\\ nonumber\\ " .
                  \ "filetype=" . a:fileType . " " . a:name

    exe l:command

    if has('nvim')
        let l:bufNr = bufnr(a:name)
        call nvim_buf_set_lines(l:bufNr, 0, -1, 0, a:lines)
    else
        call setbufline(a:name, 1, a:lines)
    endif
endfunction
```

I wrote this function based on the rust plugin code I found in the LanguageClient_neovim plugin. Thanks @D._Ben_Knoble for suggesting the vim/nvim check in the function.

Hope this helps anyone looking for this answer. I can now call this function from my callback function with the correct lines and I'm ensured that it works for me.

Comment: I believe you can check with call to make with `if has('nvim')`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks, tried and it was working under VIM too.